# Adding Windows.winmd to a UWP project cause conflict

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to create a UWP project With VS 2017 and MVVMLight tageting Windows 10 version 1803 to 1809.  It is a WPF application.

After some days of work, my solution compile and execute correctly and my main view display correctly.  Now, I need to add support for a StorageDevice and VS suggest to add a reference to Windows.winmd.  Now, StorageDevice is recognized but this add conflicts message and build errors.

The conflicts are all with Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract v7.0.0.0 for different classes including

I have many years of experience in desktop apps, but I admit I am a rookie in UWP.  I try to grasp the concept, but in my point of view, it changes year after year and I don't understand the interrelation between all the components and the concept of winmd.  So, I am lost and don't see any solution path or similar problem solution with google.

To reproduce the problem :

1. Create a MVVMLight universal windows application from Visual Studio 2017.
2. Add the following at the end of the constructor of the App class in app.xaml.cs. It will look like this :

```cs
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Suspending += OnSuspending;

   StorageFolder x = StorageDevice.FromId("");
}
```

3. Add usings for the following namespaces :

   - using Windows.Devices.Portable;
   - using Windows.Storage;
4. Compile. It will show an error for the line added in point 2 and suggest to add a reference to Windows.winmd.  StorageDevice is defined in the Windows.Devices.Portable namespace.
5. Accept the suggestion to add a reference to Windows.winmd.  The previous error disappear, but many conflicts (error CS0433) will appear, for example :

```
Erreur  CS0433  Le type 'ApplicationExecutionState' existe dans 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' et 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'    MvvmLight2  D:\Code\App.xaml.cs 41  Actif
```

Translated to english :

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'ApplicationExecutionState' exist in 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' and 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' MvvmLight2  D:\Code\App.xaml.cs 41  Actif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StorageDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.portable.storagedevice) is included in Windows Desktop Extension SDK, you do not need to add reference to Windows.winmd.

Follow the steps to add reference to 'Windows Desktop Extension':

**Right click the 'Reference' of your project -> Add Reference -> Universal Windows -> Extensions -> Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP**.

Comment: It works, thank you!  But how am I supposed to know I must ignore Visual Studio recommendation and find the right reference to use?